# Reading dynamic key value pair using spring framework java

Tags: java, spring

```
A1_M1=X1

A1_M2=X2

A1_M3=X3

A2_M1=X4

Default=X5
```

Above values are in a property file in test.properties.

I was able to do print the value of X1 for Key A1_M1 as below code.

I need some direction of how can i implement it if my key values are dynamic and i do not know Keys (of property file) until i process another object which is sent a papratmer to the class. I need to process this object to know the Keys, then look into property file if the key exist or not. If exist return the value else return a default value.

```
**spring-bean.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring--context-
                                                   3.0.xsd">

    <util:properties   id="nodeProperty"location="classpath:config/test.properties" />
        <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="nodeProperty" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.jpmc.selftutor" />

</beans>
```

Code

```
    SpringDemo.java

    package com.jpmc.selftutor;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;      
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.context.support.
                             ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    @Component("SpringDemo")
    public class SpringDemo {
     private static String a1m1;

      @Autowired
     public SpringDemo(@Value("${A1_M1}")   String a1m1){
         SpringDemo.a1m1 = a1m1;
     }

     @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new 
                  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] 
                   { "spring-bean.xml" });      
        System.out.println("Value of a1m1: " +a1m1);    

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Value annotation with default value

```
@Value("#{nodeProperty['A1_M1'] ?: nodeProperty['Default']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get the properties into your object and later you can use `getProperty()` method to check if the property value exits. If not return `getProperty("Default")`:

```
@Resource(name = "nodeProperty")
private Properties nodeProperty;
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked! You can accept the answer. :D